# CASE sql query to select encryption

Tags: sql, oracle, encryption

I have the following query

```
select distinct i.host_name, d.name, 
case 
when ts.encrypted = 'YES'
then 'ENCRYPTED' 
else 'NO'
end as ENCRYPTED 
from dba_tablespaces ts, v$encrypted_tablespaces et, v$tablespace t, v$instance I, v$database d
where t.ts#=et.ts# (+) 
and ts.tablespace_name = t.name
```

I'm looking to get result like this if ALL tablespaces on that database are encrypted

| host_name | name | ENCRYPTED |
| --- | --- | --- |
| host1000 | database | ENCRYTPED |

I want get result like this if ONLY one of the tablespace is not encrypted

| host_name | name | ENCRYPTED |
| --- | --- | --- |
| host1000 | database | NO |

This is what this query currently doing and that is not what I need. I would appreciate the help.

| host_name | name | ENCRYPTED |
| --- | --- | --- |
| host1000 | database | ENCRYTPED |
| host1000 | database | NO |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple group by query with a conditional `SUM` aggregated function

```
select   i.host_name, d.name, 
case 
when sum( case when ts.encrypted = 'NO'
          then 1 end)  > 0 then 'NO' else 'ENCRYPTED' end as encrypted
from dba_tablespaces ts, v$encrypted_tablespaces et, v$tablespace t, v$instance I, v$database d
where t.ts#=et.ts# (+) 
and ts.tablespace_name = t.name
group by i.host_name, d.name
```